# R unique multivariate integer sample

Tags: r, sampling

I want to identify two integer vectors with size equals to 50 where the first vector can vary from 0 to 20 and the second vector from 0 to 100.
The combination of the first vector and the second vector is unique (50 different couples of indices). But for example, you can select two times 1 in the first vector or two times 100 in the second one.
Bad solution:
Vector A (1, 1, ....)
Vector B (100, 100, ...)

Good solution:
Vector A (1, 1, 2, ... )
Vector B (100 , 99 , 100, ...)

At the moment I'm using:

```
a =  sample(1:20, 50,replace = T)
b = sample(1:100, 50,replace = T)
```

But of course, I have many non-unique values.

Comment: Can you clarify what you seek to do?

Comment: I don't want that the two vectors have the same combination of numbers more than one time

Answer (score 1):

You could increase your sample a bit an only keep those that have unique combinations:

```
a =  sample(1:20, 100,replace = T)
b = sample(1:100, 100,replace = T)

df <- tibble(a = a, b = b)

df %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  slice_head(n = 50)
```